# C# : Not Able to update data on database using DataGridView and SqlCeConnection

Tags: c#, datagridview

I tried everything . Not able to fix and find the work around.

Error: A parameter is missing. [ Parameter ordinal = 2 ] on command a.update(t);

Technology : C#,Visual Studio 2008

```
    public partial class Doctor : Form
    {
    SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\DBConnectionCSharp\\DBConnectionCSharp\\DBTesting1.sdf");
    SqlCeCommand cmd;
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    SqlCeDataAdapter a;
    DataSet ds;
    SqlCeCommandBuilder cam;


    public Doctor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Visible = true;
        con.Open();
        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cam = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(a);
        cmd.CommandText = "update Doctor set Name=@p2 where ID=@p1";

    }

    private void Doctor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       using (a = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Doctor", con))
        {
            a.Fill(t);
            DoctorView.DataSource = t;

        }
        con.Close();
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a.UpdateCommand = cmd;
        a.Update(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Something in your code is not quite right. In the constructor of the form you call `a.UpdateCommand = cmd;` but at this point the SqlCeDataAdapter a is not initialized. You should get a Null Reference Exception with the code above well before the Save_Click. Also in the Form Load exiting the using statement around the initialization of the DataAdapter will call Dispose on the Adapter and still you should get errors when you try to use that variable in the Save_Click. Are you sure that this is exactly your code?

Comment: Actually for debugging purpose I added extra codes. Between I am able to fetch and display data on DataViewGrid but not able to Update the modified data.

Comment: Then it is better that you update the code above and leave only the code that creates the error.

Comment: How many fields are present in the table Doctor?

Comment: Only 2,Columns are ID and Doctor_Name. I am newbie to C#.Started building application today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to change your code in this way, sorry but cannot test now...

```
public partial class Doctor : Form
{

    public Doctor()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       // Remove all the code used to initialize the global objects here
    }

    private void Doctor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Open the connection just when needed, 
       // Initialize the adapter and fill the grid
       using(SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(.....))
       {
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Doctor", con);
            a.Fill(t);
            DoctorView.DataSource = t;
       }
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       using(SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(.....))
       {

            // Prepare again the adapter with a valid select command
            SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Doctor", con);

            // Force the building of the internal command objects of the adapter
            SqlCeCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(a);

            // Recover the datatable from the datasource of the grid            
            DataTable t = DoctorView.DataSource as DataTable;

            // Update the table with DataRows changed, deleted or inserted
            a.Update(t);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 1: 

I am encountering the following error "The DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection property needs to be initialized;"

Error 2:

If I add following code
`code`
            SqlCeCommandBuilder cmd;
            cmd = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(a);
            SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand();
            cm.CommandText="update Doctor set Name=@p2 where ID=@p1";
            a.UpdateCommand =cm ;
`code`

Nothing is displayed in DataGrid

Comment: The code that initialized the DataAdapter seems correct because the connection is passed in the constructor as explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f1ae7sy(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Updated answer. tested now on a different db, but it works now

Comment: Please Clear this doubt : 
Why its working if we create another instance of SqlCeDataAdapter inside Save_click but not when we declare it in global scope ?

Comment: The problem is that we need to reapply the connection to the adapter. The using statement around the code in the form load close and dispose (as good practice requires) the connection, but, when you are in the Save_Click method, you don't have anymore a valid connection inside the adapter at the global scope. So you need to reopen the connection and reapply it to the adapter. As far as I know there is no way to assign the connection to the adapter except in the constructor call.